# How can do such a custom tab in iOS

Tags: ios, tabs

[image: Tab in iOS]

Hi all, as you can see, how can I implement a custom tab bar like above?

When you clicked one tab, the tab would be dim, and the tab would be over the other one. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard controller with such behaviour in cocoatouch, so, there are two ways to do that - first way is to implement this control by yourself from scratch,  the second way is to use custom third party control, for example: http://www.hollance.com/2011/11/mhtabbarcontroller-a-custom-tab-bar-for-ios-5-using-the-new-container-apis/

Comment: But how I do the round layout, because the standard one is just a rectangle. It is too plain and how can I custom it?